# How to draw more than one square in tkinter's Canvas?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas


master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=250, height=200)
w.pack()
w.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill="blue", outline = 'blue')
master.mainloop()
```

This creates one square/rectangle. How do I create a function so that it will create more than one square?

Answer (score 5):

How about calling `create_rectangle` repeatedly?

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=250, height=200)
w.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill="blue", outline = 'blue')
w.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill="red", outline = 'blue') 
w.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Maybe you should put a little more effort into it, it is not that hard to go from making one to makeing n.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on how to define functions in Python. I recommend the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Implementing the rectangle as a class (NOTE: For your own sake, read about functions and variables first):
[Help Creating Python Class with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479265/help-creating-python-class-with-tkinter?rq=1)